# Design for batch upload of data into CRM Cloud system

Tags: database, upload, bulk

We have to design an interface to deliver a build upload of data into CRM system which is cloud based. The bulk upload will be executed regularly to have a real time data push.
There are 2 approaches.

1. Transformed data is stored on the queue and then the schedule job executes which bulk loads the data into CRM system.
2. Transformed data is stored in the database table and then the schedule job executes which bulk loads the data into CRM system.

One of the major issue is the cloud CRM system cannot accept 2 request with same primary id's which means filtering of data before the data is uploaded.

Somehow i am not comfortable to using queues as a persistent component. Database table gives more control over error handling[system/data], persistent storage [CLOB], debugging, filtering.

Can i get the pros-cons for queue or db approach. This will help me make a design decision.
Moreover if someone can enlighten with design strategies it would be great.

Thanks in advance
Makarand Parab

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is technically called ETL of data.  There are lots of tools available to do load the data.  Are you going to write your own tool to extract and load the data.  The third approach could be to load from a file too.  Generally Queues are not used if it not realtime upload.  Abinitio is popular tool.  You can schedule the job using autosys tool.  But both are paid software.  Your design involves 2 stages.  (a) To clean data to remove duplicates (b) to load the data in CRM system.  To exactly design the interface can you please let us know what interface your CRM supports.  (File based, SQL etc.,)

Comment: We already a PUB-SUB mechanism in place and using CORDYS BPM tool.The question is w.r.t. should queues be used in such a design to store the transformed data. What is better medium of storage/filter Queues or database.

Comment: If it is realtime there is no problem in using Queues.  I have used JMS Queues before.  There has to be a filtering mechanism.  I have Openadaptor interface with JMS Queues.  You can build filter and cascade to load the data.  Source --> [data clean]-->[load data].  Openadaptor provides hospitals where you can view any errors.  If you are using your own tool, ensure there are error trapping mechanism.  Then there should be failure conditions check.  If one record is rejected should the processing stop.  If there are MAX n records rejected should it stop processing so on...

Comment: @user1323726.  Check www.openadaptor.org.  It may have some documents on its architecture.  It just helps doing what you intend to do though you can incorporate that architecture in your tool.